# All combination of list elements printed to excel using python

Tags: python, excel, combinations, openpyxl

Need to find all combinations written to an excel sheet.

```
A = ['x', 'y', 'z'] B = ['T', 'F'] C = ['GT', 'LT']
```

I want combination like follows written to excel sheet

```
x    T     GT
y    T     GT
z    T     GT
x    F     GT
y    F     GT
z    F     GT
x    T     LT
y    T     LT
z    T     LT
x    F     LT
y    F     LT
z    F     LT
```

Comment: very interesting

Comment: Cool.  What have you tried?

Comment: You already have all combinations, now put them into the Excel sheet. I think, copy-paste would work.

Comment: Hey, you need to try to solve the problem by yourself first and ask more precisely preferably with code where you need help, you will have more answer if you do so here  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `itertools.product()` to give you all of your permutation as follows:

```
from itertools import product
import openpyxl    

A = ['x', 'y', 'z'] 
B = ['T', 'F'] 
C = ['GT', 'LT']    

wb_out = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws_out = wb_out.active
ws_out.title = "Permutations"

for p in product(A, B, C):
    ws_out.append(p)

wb_out.save(filename='permutations.xlsx')
```

The `openpyxl` library can be used to create an proper Excel XLSX file.

---

If by Excel file you actually mean a CSV file:

```
from itertools import product
import csv

A = ['x', 'y', 'z'] 
B = ['T', 'F'] 
C = ['GT', 'LT']    

with open('permutations.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerows(product(A, B, C))
```

Giving you:

```
x,T,GT
x,T,LT
x,F,GT
x,F,LT
y,T,GT
y,T,LT
y,F,GT
y,F,LT
z,T,GT
z,T,LT
z,F,GT
z,F,LT
```

Tested on Python 2.x